# Cascading MultiMapping with Dapper

Tags: dapper

I'm porting some slow code from EF6 to Dapper, since now I've successfully manage the mapping using the function `(x,y) =>{x.Mapped = mapped}`

Now I'm in the following case
I've an Entity A that refers to B that referes to C

```
var cliente = connection.Query<BENEFIT_POLIZZE, BENEFIT_CLIENTI, 
 var cliente = connection.Query<BENEFIT_POLIZZE, BENEFIT_CLIENTI, BENEFIT_POLIZZE>(
                            "SELECT * FROM BENEFIT_POLIZZE [Extent1] INNER JOIN [dbo].[BENEFIT_CLIENTI] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID_CLIENTE] = [Extent2].[ID_CLIENTE] WHERE ID_POLIZZA_BENEFIT = @ID_POLIZZA_BENEFIT",

                            (polizza, clienteo) =>
                            {
                               polizza.BENEFIT_CLIENTI = clienteo;
                                return polizza;

                            }, param:new {ID_POLIZZA_BENEFIT = idPolizza}, splitOn:"ID_CLIENTE").Distinct().Single();
```

Now I've to reference a field that's defined at `cliente.GRUPPO_CLIENTE_MAIN`

is this possible? I don't see the possibility to set another function to define cascading relation

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind that with this approach you still *can't* deal with 1:N relationships, you can surely have multiple 1:1 relationship. While it is not possible for me to show a sample directly using your code since you didn't provide enough information (for example how cliente.GRUPPO_CLIENTE_MAIN would relate to the existing code?) Here's the full explanation along with sample source code:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/multiple-mapping-d36c637d14fa